# Jquery slidetoggle бархлит

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте,

Есть сайт http://soltis-adr.ru/. На нем есть корзина. Корзина имеет раскрывающийся список товаров, реализованный средствами jQuery. Но раскрытие отрабатывает с некоторыми артефактами. Как будто список разворачивается и сворачивается не от верха а от линии, в обе стороны, линия пикселей на 5 ниже верха. На сайте видно сразу.

Если у кого то какие нибудь соображения, подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это знакомое поведение списков. Самый простой выход из положения - обернуть его в **div** и методы **.slideUp()**/**.slideDown()** или **.slideToggle()** повесить именно на него.

P.S. Добавил [простой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5dLUC/), в котором можно увидеть, как будет вести себя список, если его "*сворачивать/разворачивать*", как самостоятельный элемент и дочерний, когда метод применен к "родителю".

Comment: Не помогло, внешне изменилось, но основная проблема осталась.

Comment: @temoffey, в вашем коде, я вижу, что вы не убрали **slideToggle()** со списка! Оставьте его в покое и повесьте методы на родительский элемент **div.items**!

Comment: Там ("#items").parent() было. Поменял на ("div.items"), не изменилось.

Comment: ul обернуть в div?

Comment: Уже обернул